# I need to create new google meet link but without creating event in google calendar. I tried creating link with google calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-meet

```
result=self.gmeet_service.events().insert(calendarId='primary',body=event,conferenceDataVersion=1).execute()
```

I need a link without event in google calendar

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*There is no direct API for Google Meet, so at present creating a Google Meet link without creating a Calendar event is not possible.*

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. I think the best component to file this under would be the [Google Chat component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191645&template=823908), as there is currently no Google Meet API, but when filling out the form explain that this is for the creation of a Google Meet API with the intention of programmatically creating Meet rooms.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to get google meet link without creating the google calendar event** till now as there is **no Google Meet API**, we have to perform all the CRUD operations on google calendar itself.